# ClassNotFound Exceptions when class exists, and declared in Manifest

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been getting this error every since importing my existing project into a new workspace.

```
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.fttech.full_version_hippos/com.fttech.hh.MenuActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fttech.hh.MenuActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.fttech.hh-1.apk]
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1739)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fttech.hh.MenuActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.fttech.hh-1.apk]
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
02-12 11:30:58.140: E/AndroidRuntime(16605):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
```

Here is my manifest and everything else is in the correct package in my source folder.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fttech.hh"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

   <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MenuActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Arcade_MainGame"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainGame"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyPreferenceClass"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".unlockable"></activity>


</application>
</manifest>
```

Anyone see what im doing wrong?

Comment: paste entire code of MenuActivity

Comment: I dont believe it has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: As i tried changing the default activity to other activities, and the same thing.

Comment: have u declared the class as public? `public class MenuActivity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it's in the manifest.  Does MenuActivity have the right `package`?  Is MenuActivity present in the .apk?

Comment: Yes it has the right package name of com.fttech.hh It is present in the src package folder so it should be present in the .apk. if you look at the ClassNotFound exception you it is adding a -1.apk to the end of the apk file. Not sure if it should be this way.

Comment: The -1 is harmless. Have you really checked the package? An APK is just a zip file; its contents are easily confirmed.

Comment: Yes ive doubled checked, trippled check...Its really fustrating. Ive tried everything.

Comment: Also ive integrated openfient with my project, and its generating two R.java files one for my package and another for openfient package.

Comment: That's harmless as well. If the package is correct and the APK's contents are correct, then the third possibility is that you're testing a stale install from when eithe wasn't true -- but you say you've edited the manifest and have seen the same failure with other activities. So, it must not be failing then :-)

Comment: So what do you think it could be?

Comment: I think you've the wrong package, or that your APK doesn't have what you think it has.  You don't have to post the entire source of MainActivity, you can strip the imports and the body of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seemed that i had a library and  a jar in my build path, both doing the same thing. After removing one. It seemed to work!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using  Google play services ? if you are using latest Google play services and facing class not found exception then update application class

**Step 1:**

```
public class MyAppCtx extends Application {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

**Step 2:** 
updated `build.gradle` file:

```
defaultConfig {
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**Step 3 :**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Try this and Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

My live app started throwing Activity Not Found Exception w/o ANY code change. Accepted answer above gave me some clue that my environment is broken. The link below explains the ADT changes that broke my environment/project.

I used to disable export of "Android Private Libraries" to work with ProGuard. Change in classpath configuration fixed the problem and that was to mark  ”Android Private Libraries” container to be exported.

Hope this helps someone -

http://calyx.hr/weird-runtime-error-after-upgrading-android-development-tools-to-version-22/