# Classnotfound exception even when there is class declared

Tags: android

My app runs fine when i run it through eclipse, but when i export it and then install it through adb install and run, it crashes with following stacktrace.

basically, it says that main launcher activity not found, although it is declared, and is set to main activity with launcher category:

**Stacktrace:**

```
01-24 11:50:59.029: E/AndroidRuntime(7768): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.nitinbansal85.android.carplexindia/com.nitinbansal85.android.carplexindia.ActivityDashboard}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nitinbansal85.android.carplexindia.ActivityDashboard in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@32518de0
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1914)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4420)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:924)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:682)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nitinbansal85.android.carplexindia.ActivityDashboard in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@32518de0
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
01-24 11:50:59.299: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):     ... 11 more
01-24 11:51:01.369: E/msm7k.gralloc(1281): [unregister] handle 0x43bf20 still locked (state=40000001)
```

Im also using `facebook sdk`, and `airpush` and `startApp sdk's`, and have included them in order import/export

Any suggestions whats going wrong?

thanx in advance
**EDIT**

Forget to mention that i had renamed my project and folder that contained it.

Comment: Have you included relatively in build path as an extra lib?

Comment: @Pratik : i have no idea of that as im from c,c++ background. can u please explain a bit

Comment: have you declared ActivityDashboard in manifest File?

Comment: yes its there, thats why it is running when i run it through eclipse

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal : sory, cant...but trust me, its there, and is working on running from eclipse. and pleaee see my edit...

Comment: check your package name in manifest.xml

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal : although i have checked , let me do it again. And , if u have could you please look into this comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250390/classnotfound-exceptions-when-class-exists-and-declared-in-manifest     ......the comment that says: "Thanks for your help. It seemed that i had a library and a jar in my build path, both doing the same thing. After removing one. It seemed to work!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an android app, I'd same issue with an external jar file. In my case the solution was to move the jar from "lib" folder to the android default "libs" folder.

When the jar was in lib folder (was added to build path as well), while there are was no build issue in Eclipse, the app was giving ClassNotFoundException at runtime. Once I moved the jar to "libs" folder, the jar started appearing under "Android Dependencies" and app started working fine.

These are some of the other discussions about the same topic.

```
1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-    android-project

2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185488/android-what-is-the-folder-name-of-the-jar-files-lib-or-libs

3)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611105/how-to-specify-lib-folder-for-jars-when-using-android-generated-ant-build-file
```

may this could help...!!!!!

Comment: that was of help, but i believe this solution applies to ADK's that are newer. Im using ADK correspoonding to API 7. But still, let me try. thnx :)

Comment: WOW....got it working! your 3rd link's accepted answer was the key. thnx sooo much :-)

Answer (score 0):

As the Stacktrace tells that android first starts the NewActivity -> LoadClass -> FindClass -> ClassNotFoundException, could be:

- wrong package declaration in Manifest(com.nitinbansal85.android.carplexindia.ActivityDashboard)
- Android Debug Bridge(ADB) apk creation problem.
- Failed to load other jars from libs

  You can also try compiling the project from eclipse and use .apk directly from bin directory of your project and check the difference.

Comment: Ensure that you have a folder named "libs" with an 's'. Put all of your jar files that you added inside it and add to build path and also package defined at the top of the manifest file and make sure that it matches the package where you class is defined.
If it still doesn't work, create a new project and copy inside it all your java classes.

Comment: yes, it has to be libs, not lib...see my own answer to my question...thnx anywayz... :)